# Solr hanging on core loading

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I recently set up a new application using a simple Solr server with the standard jetty server:

`java -jar start.jar` from my example/ dir and I'm up and running.

Obviously I can access Solr admin and see my empty core. I can restart many time this empty Solr instance, and it always works as expected.

Then I setup a data import handler for importing 36.000 product-related documents from a MySQL datasource and it works fine. In less than 10 seconds I have my index ready to be queried.

Finally I shutdown my server (it is a test aws-ec2 instance).

When I start my server again, `java -jar start.jar` is executed on startup. 
Solr logs do not show any errors or warnings, but when I access Solr admin and try to select my core... it just hangs on "loading..." with no messages in logs, until timeout :-((

[image]

The only way to get that back working, is to delete all content in *solr/mycore/data* directory, then restart and re-import/re-index content.

Where I can get more infos on what's happening?

Could my brutal shutdown operation be the cause for core corruption or something else? Thank you

**EDIT**

I changed

```
<useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
<maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
```

to:

```
<useColdSearcher>true</useColdSearcher>
<maxWarmingSearchers>1</maxWarmingSearchers>
```

and now it works. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is your OS a unix system? If so, probably the mount point of the solr_home is full. We had that on a test machine once. The symptoms where the same, it was so full that not even one further log-message went out. So solr went stale, as it wanted to log that it is starting.

Comment: Perhaps solr is trying to start before everything is mounted correctly? You didn't say whether you could restart just solr after indexing. If you can restart and query just fine before restarting the box, then it might be a timing issue on startup.